need to see what I'm typing (passwords)
I have had lots of antidepressants tested on me, and while that's been stopped in my horror I still have hands that do what they want alot.
I need to be able to see my password when prompted by my computer. I seem to always mess it up, especially when blinded to the characters. I'm using the neptune Debian-based operating system (version 8) and am brand new learning these things and trying to setup my stuff over here as admin. Don't want to bypass being prompted really, too many hacker exes...however I need to SEE the thing I'm typing and am usually alone when on. Is there Any way to change this so I can?

Type it in a text editor and copy-paste. Use a password manager and copy-paste.

edcozz, is this for a graphical login, or for the command line?

@ChrisDavies, mostly for command line. That's tough enough without password nonsense. But I prefer to have the option to see it everywhere. Thanks

@muru I dud actually try to copy and paste, but nit with a password manager. Now I see why computer ppl.are on all day ! There's alot to learn and do
